# Monospace text vs. Monospaced text

Tags: word-choice, difference

> *`foo bar baz`*

What is the correct way to describe the example above?

Is it correct to say the example is typed in **monospace** italic?

Or is it correct to say that it is typed in **monospaced** italic?

The difference seems to be very thin, and I cannot find any explanations whether one form is correct and another is not, or whether one form is preferred over another. And what is the difference at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general description of the typeface, "monospaced" is better.

You might use "monospace italic" as part of a formal font description string or name of a font.

For example I can find:

> Victor Mono is an open-source monospaced font with optional semi-connected cursive italics.

> That change also led me to explore monospaced fonts suitable for coding.

However there is variation and it *isn't wrong* to use "monospace":

> Monospace fonts can mimic a typewriter or computer.

(all examples found by web search)